# HTML: parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, html

Can we put a string parameter in a JS function, while i'm in html? Like this:

```
<form name="form3" action="mat.py" method="get" onsubmit="return validation(param1,param2)"/>
```

I can also say that i'm working in Python, so my code is like that: there's just two ' ', i don't think it can deal damages

```
 print'<form name="form3" action="mat.py" method="get" onsubmit="return validation(param1,param2)"/>'
```

I included my JS in an other file

Thank you, 
Clément.

Comment: the action attribute is to be a url.  What is mat.py?  It can't be a script

Comment: @joelgoldstick: That `action` is fine. It submits to the relative URL `mat.py`, which presumably is Python run by the server just like `mat.php` would be PHP run by the server or `mat.jsp` would be Java run by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. I made an HUGE mistake: i forgot this on the .js file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There are *three layers* to this statement:

```python
print'<form name="form3" action="mat.py" method="get" onsubmit="return validation(param1,param2)"/>'
```

There's

1. The Python layer, the whole HTML thing is one big string in `'` quotes.
2. The HTML layer, which is putting the attribute values in `"` quotes.
3. The JavaScript layer, where you don't currently have any quotes.

It's important to keep track of what's happening at each level.

So, you have a couple of options:

1. Outputting JavaScript code inside HTML attribuets is why JavaScript originally had two kinds of quotes (it now has three), both `"` and `'`. So you can use `\` in your Python code to put `'` around the params:

   ```python
   print'<form name="form3" action="mat.py" method="get" onsubmit="return validation(\'param1\', \'param2\')"/>'
   ```

   That outputs this:

   ```html
   <form name="form3" action="mat.py" method="get" onsubmit="return validation('param1', 'param2')"/>'
   ```

   Note we're using `'` around the JavaScript strings, so as not to end the HTML attribute early.

   It also works if we use `'` for the HTML attribute quotes and `"` in the JavaScript, since HTML also allows both kinds of quotes:

   ```python
   print'<form name=\'form3\' action=\'mat.py'\ method=\'get\' onsubmit=\'return validation("param1", "param2")\'/>'
   ```

   which outputs

   ```html
   <form name='form3' action='mat.py' method='get' onsubmit='return validation("param1", "param2")'/>
   ```
2. Remember that the content of HTML attributes **is HTML**, so you can use `&quot;`, the named character entity for `"`:

   ```python
   print'<form name="form3" action="mat.py" method="get" onsubmit="return validation(&quot;param1&quot;, &quot;param2&quot;)"/>'
   ```

   which outputs

   ```html
   <form name="form3" action="mat.py" method="get" onsubmit="return validation(&quot;param1&quot;, &quot;param2&quot;)"/>
   ```

   Not very readable though. :-)

But your best option is *don't use `onxyz` attribute handlers at all*, use modern techniques for hooking up events.

Comment: (i'm writing) It doesn't work. I don't think that HTML understand that this is a parameter. It takes it like a string,: for him, it's "param1" and not my param1. 

What kind of "modern techniques"?

Comment: @ClémentB: Sorry, I'd missed the Python bit. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 252, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2016 15:26:46] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

Here's the problem. I don't know why, but your code doesn't work.